# Terraform, RDS (Postgres) and Production

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-rds, terraform-provider-azure

How does one use Terraform to deploy a Postgres database to RDS in Production?

I am currently running Terraform run locally, deploying my RDS instance to an AWS environment. However, in-order to create the Postgres resources (using the provider from cyrilgdn), I have to make my RDS instance publicly available. This is frowned upon in PROD environments, for obvious reasons. So how do people get around this for PROD Terraform deployed environments? I'm thinking the only way would be to run Terraform from within the RDS private subnet of the VPC... but how is that even possible?? Or am I missing something important :S

```
provider "aws" {
    access_key          = var.aws_access_key
    secret_key          = var.aws_secret_key
    region              = var.aws_region
    default_tags {
      tags = {
        Owner             = var.owner
        Environment       = var.env
      }
    }
}

resource "aws_security_group" "db-rules" {
  name = "rds-sec-grp"
  vpc_id = var.rds_vpc_id

  tags = {
    Name = "rds-sec-grp"
  }

  ingress {
    from_port        = "5432"
    to_port          = "5432"
    protocol         = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks      = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }

  egress {
    from_port        = 0
    to_port          = 0
    protocol         = "-1"
    cidr_blocks      = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }
}

resource "aws_db_instance" "default" {
    identifier          = "db-instance"
    allocated_storage   = 10
    engine              = "postgres"
    engine_version      = "13.2"
    port                = 5432
    instance_class      = "db.t3.medium"
    multi_az            = false
    name                = "db_system_${var.env}"
    username            = var.db_master_username
    password            = var.db_master_password
    publicly_accessible = true
    skip_final_snapshot = true
    db_subnet_group_name =    var.rds_public_subnet_group
    vpc_security_group_ids =  [aws_security_group.db-rules.id]

    tags = {
      Name = "db-instance"
    }
}

provider "postgresql" {
  host                  = aws_db_instance.default.address
  port                  = aws_db_instance.default.port
  database              = aws_db_instance.default.name
  username              = var.db_master_username
  password              = var.db_master_password
  superuser             = false
  sslmode               = "require"
  connect_timeout       = 15
  expected_version      = aws_db_instance.default.engine_version
}

resource "postgresql_database" "default" {
  name                  = "db_${var.env}"
  owner                 = var.db_master_username
}

resource "postgresql_role" "readonly" {
  name                  = var.db_readonly_username
  password              = var.db_readonly_password
  login                 = true
  connection_limit      = 5
}

resource "postgresql_role" "readwrite" {
  name                  = var.db_readwrite_username
  password              = var.db_readwrite_password
  login                 = true
  connection_limit      = 5
}

resource "postgresql_role" "migrator" {
  name                  = var.db_migrator_username
  password              = var.db_migrator_password
  login                 = true
  connection_limit      = 5
}

resource "postgresql_schema" "ps" {
  name                  = "ps"
  database              = postgresql_database.default.name
  owner                 = var.db_master_username
}

resource "postgresql_grant" "revoke_public_schema" {
  database              = postgresql_database.default.name
  role                  = "public"
  schema                = "public"
  object_type           = "schema"
  privileges            = []
}

resource "postgresql_grant" "readonly_schema" {
  database              = postgresql_database.default.name
  role                  = postgresql_role.readonly.name
  schema                = postgresql_schema.ps.name
  object_type           = "schema"
  privileges            = ["USAGE"]
  depends_on = [
    postgresql_grant.revoke_public_schema
  ]
}

resource "postgresql_grant" "readwrite_schema" {
  database              = postgresql_database.default.name
  role                  = postgresql_role.readwrite.name
  schema                = postgresql_schema.ps.name
  object_type           = "schema"
  privileges            = ["USAGE"]
  depends_on = [
    postgresql_grant.readonly_schema
  ]
}

resource "postgresql_grant" "migrator_schema" {
  database              = postgresql_database.default.name
  role                  = postgresql_role.migrator.name
  schema                = postgresql_schema.ps.name
  object_type           = "schema"
  privileges            = ["CREATE", "USAGE"]
  depends_on = [
    postgresql_grant.readwrite_schema
  ]
}

resource "postgresql_grant" "readonly" {
  database              = postgresql_database.default.name
  role                  = postgresql_role.readonly.name
  schema                = postgresql_schema.ps.name
  object_type           = "table"
  privileges            = ["SELECT"]
  depends_on = [
    postgresql_grant.migrator_schema
  ]
}

resource "postgresql_grant" "readwrite" {
  database              = postgresql_database.default.name
  role                  = postgresql_role.readwrite.name
  schema                = postgresql_schema.ps.name
  object_type           = "table"
  privileges            = ["SELECT", "INSERT", "UPDATE", "DELETE"]
  depends_on = [
    postgresql_grant.migrator_schema
  ]
}

resource "postgresql_grant" "migrator" {
  database              = postgresql_database.default.name
  role                  = postgresql_role.migrator.name
  schema                = postgresql_schema.ps.name
  object_type           = "table"
  privileges            = ["INSERT"]
  depends_on = [
    postgresql_grant.migrator_schema
  ]
}

resource "aws_ecr_repository" "webapi" {
  name                 = "webapi"

  image_scanning_configuration {
    scan_on_push = true
  }
}

resource "aws_ecr_repository" "service" {
  name                 = "pollingservice"

  image_scanning_configuration {
    scan_on_push = true
  }
}

resource "aws_ecr_repository" "migration" {
  name                 = "datamigrations"

  image_scanning_configuration {
    scan_on_push = true
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, why you database should be public? What's wrong with having it private?

Comment: I'm saying it SHOULD be private. I have to make it publicly available, otherwise Terraform can't connect to the instance to create the Postgres resources on it. The question is, how can I still use Terraform as I am now, but with a private RDS instance.

Comment: Can you be more clear? What instance? Do you have any actual TF code to show demonstrating your issue?

Comment: Added TF. The issue is, if I set `publicly_accessible = false`, the side-effect is that the postgres provider crashes

Comment: you would need a bastion server. I can't prescribe what type or how one should be set up, but this wikipedia article is a good starting point: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bastion_host. Once the bastion is set up, you'd run TF from there to deploy your infrastructure.

Comment: Ahhh, I had seen the name a few times in my searches, but it meant nothing too me... will look into that deeper :)

Comment: I see, TF [docs suggests](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/cyrilgdn/postgresql/latest/docs#gocloud) to use GoCloud for this purpose. Have you tried that?

Comment: Not yet... will read up on that also :)

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I'm stuck trying to use the Postresql provider with an RDS instance that isn't publicly available but was deployed from Terraform Cloud